# Retrieving data from a service class .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have a class that contains different characteristics for a pokemon

```
    public ObservableCollection<Pokemon> GetMesPokemons()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Pokemon> lstPokemons =
                new ObservableCollection<Pokemon>();
            lstPokemons.Add(new Pokemon()
            {
                NamePokemon = "Raichu",
                UrlImage = "https://i0.wp.com/pokemon-suisse.ch/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/img_1517.jpg?resize=1536%2C2048&ssl=1",
                Abilities = new List<Ability>()
                {
                    new Ability
                    {
                        Name = "Thunderbolt",
                        NbPower = 120
                    },
                    new Ability
                    {
                        Name = "Spark Ball GX",
                        NbPower = 200
                    }
                },
                PokemonClass = new PokemonType()
                {
                    NameClass = "Electric",
                    UrlImage = "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.T-kNLsS_VhinWEuPIfZdHAHaHk?w=159&h=180&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7"
                },
                Pv = 210
```

I can get the name of the pokemon and its image and pv, but when I try to get its "Abilities" I get this message on the display: System.Collections.Generic.List'1[MauiApp2.Models.Ability]

This is how I try to get it back

```
      <CollectionView
            x:Name="PokemonsAbilities"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AbilitiesSource}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AbilitiesTemplate}">
        </CollectionView>

        <!--Récupération de l'image d'un pokemonRandom-->
        <Image Source="{Binding SelectedPokemon.UrlImage}" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"/>

        <!--Récupération du nom d'un pokemonrandom-->
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding SelectedPokemon.NamePokemon}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label 
            Text="{Binding SelectedPokemon.Pv}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label 
            Text="{Binding SelectedPokemon.Abilities}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

This is my Pokemon model

```
public class Pokemon
    {

        private string  _namePokemon;

        public string NamePokemon
        {
            get { return _namePokemon; }
            set { _namePokemon = value; }
        }

        private string _urlImage;


        public string UrlImage
        {
            get { return _urlImage; }
            set { _urlImage = value; }
        }

        private int _pv;

        public int Pv
        {
            get { return _pv; }
            set { _pv = value; }
        }

        public List<Ability> Abilities { get; set; }
```

This is my Ability model

```
   public class Ability
    {

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private int _nbPower;

        public int NbPower
        {
            get { return _nbPower; }
            set { _nbPower = value; }
        }
```

My template

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="LstPokemons">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--<Button Text="Profil"></Button>-->
                    <Image Source="{Binding UrlImage}" Grid.Column="2" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150"></Image>
                    <Label Text="{Binding NamePokemon}" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="Abilities">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding NbPower}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

My "PokemonView" page representing my two View collections based on my two DataTemplates one to retrieve the list of pokemons and the other to retrieve the abilities of a pokemon

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:PokemonViewModel></vm:PokemonViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Pseudo}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label Text="Voici les pokemons disponible pour un match"></Label>

        <!--Collectionview : qui contient mon template pour afficher une grid qui va contenir des pokémons 
        On peut en sélectionner un à la fois-->
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="Pokemons"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LstPokemons}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListPokemons}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedItem="{Binding MonSelectedPokemon}">
        </CollectionView>

        <CollectionView
            x:Name="PokemonsAbilities"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AbilitiesTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AbilitiesSource}">
        </CollectionView>

        <!--Boutton pour passer a la page suivante une fois qu'il a séléctionné un pokémon-->
            <Button x:Name="btnValidate" Text="Valider" Command="{Binding ValidateSelected}"></Button>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: @Jason Excuse me, I just put it on

Comment: If you’re referring to the final Label, you can’t bind a list of objects to a single label.  You either need to use a templated control, or add a property to your VM that will return a single string value for the collection

Comment: You have two or three different things named `Abilities`. Might be easier to see what is wrong, if you give them all different names. E.g. the DataTemplate could be `AbilitiesTemplate`, the source that is bound to ItemsSource could be `AbilitiesSource`. Or if that is a list of Pokemon, `PokemonList`. I can't see from the source you show, how `lstPokemons` is used. Also confusing is `CollectionView x:Name="Pokemons"`, which then has ItemsSource `Abilities`. Which is it? Is it viewing Pokemons, or is it viewing Abilities of a single Pokemon? Can't be both at same time.

Comment: @Jason Yes I use a model for my abilities and another model for my pokemon list with the abilities list to be able to get the final info from my pokemon list. What would be the property I need to add and where?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT 
Yes I use two dataTemplates : lstPokemons which represent my list of pokemons and Abilities which represent the abilities of a pokemon coming from the dataTemplates lstPokemons. Is it better to put everything in one dataTemplate or can I keep 2?  
I just added my code representing the PokemonView page with my two collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a property in your model that will convert your list of Ability objects into a string that you can display in a Label

```
public string AbilitiesDesc
{
  get 
  {
    return string.Join(",", Abilities.Select(a => a.Name));
  }
}
```

Then bind this new property to the Label

```
<Label 
        Text="{Binding SelectedPokemon.AbilitiesDesc}"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

Comment: What is "Select" for and how should I implement it?

Comment: It’s a LINQ query.  Add “using System.Linq;” to your class

Comment: It's weird I can't implement it with "using System.Linq;
I can just generate the method

Comment: The code you sent me, is it in the behind code or in the Model view?

Comment: It’s a property on your model

Comment: if you're still having problems, you need to provide specific details about the problem and any errors or exceptions you're getting